# How to write compile and make log in Dockerfile?

Tags: php, docker, compilation, docker-compose, dockerfile

**I put logging configure options into Dockerfile but logs file not created, why?**
This is correctly working in host OS, but not working in Docker.
And to the source directory does not set permissions to the 777, but set 755.

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV PHP_VERSION 5.6.22
ENV PHP_PREFIX /opt/php/"$PHP_VERSION"/
...
...
ENV PHP_SRC /opt/src/php/
RUN mkdir -p "$PHP_SRC"
WORKDIR "$PHP_SRC"
...
ADD ./php-"$PHP_VERSION".tar.gz "$PHP_SRC"
RUN cd "$PHP_SRC" && \
cd "$PHP_SRC"php-"$PHP_VERSION" && \
chmod -R 777 . && \
./configure \
--prefix="$PHP_PREFIX" \
--with-config-file-path="$PHP_PREFIX"etc \
...
...
> configure.log 2>&1 && \
make -j"$(nproc)" > make.log 2>&1 && \
make install > install.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with change this:

```
...
...
> configure.log 2>&1 && \
make -j"$(nproc)" > make.log 2>&1 && \
make install > install.log 2>&1
```

...to this:

```
...
...
2> configure.log && \
make -j"$(nproc)" 2> make.log && \
make install 2> install.log
```

**But before I set to the appropriate authority!**